# Spring SOAP Ws client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

i'm struggling trying to call, for example puroposes, a soap ws exposed with SpringWS:

Here it is my wsdl deployed on tomcat..

```
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-b01-.-->
<!--Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-b01-.-->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/" name="HelloWorldWSService" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.mkyong.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
   <types>
      <xsd:schema>
         <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/web_services/hello?xsd=1"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="findById">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findById"/>
   </message>
   <message name="findByIdResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findByIdResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="saveJob">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:saveJob"/>
   </message>
   <message name="saveJobResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:saveJobResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="findJobByName">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findJobByName"/>
   </message>
   <message name="findJobByNameResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findJobByNameResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="findJobByRole">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findJobByRole"/>
   </message>
   <message name="findJobByRoleResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:findJobByRoleResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="deleteJob">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteJob"/>
   </message>
   <message name="deleteJobResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteJobResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getAllJobs">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllJobs"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getAllJobsResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllJobsResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="updateJob">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateJob"/>
   </message>
   <message name="updateJobResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateJobResponse"/>
   </message>
   <portType name="HelloWorldWS">
      <operation name="findById">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findByIdRequest" message="tns:findById"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findByIdResponse" message="tns:findByIdResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="saveJob">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/saveJobRequest" message="tns:saveJob"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/saveJobResponse" message="tns:saveJobResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="findJobByName">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findJobByNameRequest" message="tns:findJobByName"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findJobByNameResponse" message="tns:findJobByNameResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="findJobByRole">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findJobByRoleRequest" message="tns:findJobByRole"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/findJobByRoleResponse" message="tns:findJobByRoleResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="deleteJob">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/deleteJobRequest" message="tns:deleteJob"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/deleteJobResponse" message="tns:deleteJobResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getAllJobs">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/getAllJobsRequest" message="tns:getAllJobs"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/getAllJobsResponse" message="tns:getAllJobsResponse"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="updateJob">
         <input wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/updateJobRequest" message="tns:updateJob"/>
         <output wsam:Action="http://ws.mkyong.com/HelloWorldWS/updateJobResponse" message="tns:updateJobResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="HelloWorldWSPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldWS">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <operation name="findById">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="saveJob">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="findJobByName">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="findJobByRole">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="deleteJob">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getAllJobs">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="updateJob">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="HelloWorldWSService">
      <port name="HelloWorldWSPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldWSPortBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/web_services/hello"/>
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

i would like to define a simple client to test it, with a main method would be great, calling them with SpringWS, if you give me some suggestions or link it would be great, maybe an example about how to call them sending an Object as request parameter and sending a empty input request, in the case the WS method is without parameters.

Any reference to link or code snippet would be a great help, i found so many different examples, no one suits my needs, and im getting a little bit confused now..

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to go with **Spring WebServiceTemplate**

WebServiceTemplate - 
        The WebServiceTemplate is the core class for client-side Web service access in Spring-WS. It contains methods for sending Source objects, and receiving response messages as either Source or Result. Additionally, it can marshal objects to XML before sending them across a transport, and unmarshal any response XML into an object again.

Step 1:

Sample Example generate Object using WSDL:

```
   1. Copy you are WSDL file into local directory
   2. Open Command Promote
   3. wsimport -p mypackage -keep -verbose myservice.wsdl

 This command generated object request and response
```

Step 2:
     ApplicationContext.xml configuration for Soap Message Factory

```
    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
   <property name="soapVersion">
       <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Step 3:Marshaller Configuration

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="contextPaths" value="package"/>
  </bean>
```

Step 4: WebServiceTemplate Configuration

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>              
    <property name="defaultUri" value="wsdlLocation" />
  </bean>
```

Step 5:

Prepare Connection Client:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

class ClientConnection {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public synchronized Object sendRequestAndReceive(Object xmlRequest,
            final String uri) {
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(uri);
        Object object = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(xmlRequest);
        return object;
    }
}
```

Please refer below link, for more information.

[Spring WS Template example](http://cdevzone.blogspot.in/p/spring-templatewsdl-client.html?m=1)